# How to use sed to replace a string in a file with a filename?

Tags: string, awk, sed, replace

There are two files:

index.html

polyfills-es2015.XXXXXXXXXX.js

And this `XXXXXXXXXX` part of the filename changes after building an app, and usually looks like hash `b4f0746c57e75f62cef6`.

index.html contains the line:

```
<script src="polyfills-es2015.YYYYYYYYYYY.js"></script>
```

How can I take `XXXXXXXXXX` part of the filename and put it instead of `YYYYYYYYYYY` part of the string in index.html using `sed` or `awk` in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/polyfills-es2015.\..*\.js/'$(echo polyfills-es2015.*.js)'/' index.html
```

With `echo` and globbing find out the current filename. This filename is than placed in the sed command using a subshell `$(..)`. `sed` here looks for the `polyfills-es2015.\..*.js` regex and replaces it with the new file.

I do think there are better solutions regarding the webdev build process than some crappy unix commands, but if this is the only thing, it will probably work.